# How can i change my css overflow depending on the content?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making my own dropdown with CSS. You hover on it, then some options appear below it, you pick one and that's it. If there are too many options to fit there is a scroll bar. You can see the whole thing here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jesper02/o4uxzLe0/130/)

```js
let testData = [
    "qwertyuiop",
    "asdfghjkl",
    "zxcvbnm",
    "axdxfcbhdhvhv",
    "äöäööäöääöää",
    "zoinkszoinks",
    "brrrrrrrrrr",
    "gygygygyasdasda",
];

getTestStuff();

function getTestStuff() {
    let content = document.getElementById("content");
    let text = document.getElementById("text");
    for (let group of testData) {
        let div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = group;
        div.addEventListener("click", function() { 
            text.innerHTML = group; // update button text
        }, false);

        content.appendChild(div);
    }
}

let dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown");
let arrow = document.getElementById("arrow");
let content = document.getElementById("content");
dropdown.addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {
    arrow.className = "open";
    content.classList.add("open");
}, false); 

dropdown.addEventListener("mouseleave", function () {
    arrow.className = "closed";
    content.classList.remove("open");
}, false);
```

```css
.dropdown-wrapper {
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 5px;
}

.dropdown-wrapper, .dropdown-content {
    width: 300px;
}

.dropdown-wrapper .header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    display: table; 
}

.dropdown-wrapper .header span {
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      display: table-cell;
      width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-wrapper .header div span {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.dropdown-wrapper .header div {
    margin-left: -40px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    float: none;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content div {
    color: black;
    float: none;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    margin-right: -15px;
}

.dropdown-content div:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}


#arrow.open {
    -webkit-animation-name: openArrowAnimation;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#arrow.closed {
    -webkit-animation-name: closeArrowAnimation;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes openArrowAnimation {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes closeArrowAnimation {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

#content.open {
    -webkit-animation-name: openDropdownAnimation;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes openDropdownAnimation {
  from {
    max-height: 0px;
  }
  to {
    max-height: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
 <div class="dropdown-wrapper">
     <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown">
         <div class="header">
             <span id="text">Test Thing</span>
             <div id="arrow"><span>^</span></div>
         </div>
         <div id="content" class="dropdown-content">
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**The Problem**:

1. The scrollbar appears during my animation. Which is not a problem, if it is going to stay, but when the content fits, it disappears again.
2. When the scroll bar is not there, the space that the scrollbar would take, does not have the right background color, when i hover over the option. Making a very ugly gap.

I know about `overflow: auto;` but i still use `overflow: scroll;`  with `margin-right: -16px;` on the children, because my scrollbar moves the children and i only have that scrollbar sometimes.

I need some kind of CSS conditional hack to set `overflow` to hidden if we don't need it or use JS to change the `margin-right` but trying to check the parent height after adding the kids gave me this:

> content.height: undefined
>
> content.style.height: empty string

So i'm very lost with this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, so i'm asking: Do you want to change the css from the parent node depending on the content of the child node? Thats not possible with css only

Comment: I'm not really looking for any specific solution to this problem. I've seen some css hacks using [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()) but i don't understand them enough to edit any solution i find to fit my problem.

Comment: If you are "not searching for a specific solution", then this question is off-topic.

Comment: 2. is due to the fact that you set `overflow-y: scroll;`, forcing a "placeholder" for a potential scrollbar. If you don't want that, set `auto` instead.

Comment: _"but trying to check the parent height after adding the kids gave me this: content.height: undefined, content.style.height: empty string"_ - `element.height` is not a thing, if anything, you'd need to look at `offsetHeight` or `scrollHeight`. And reading `element.style.foobar` only works, if the style was set inline/via JS to begin with, it does _not_ reflect anything applied via your stylesheet.

Comment: @CBroe Like i said in my question, the problem with `auto` is that i have a negative margin on my children, so that they are still centered, after the scrollbar moves them a little. Then when the scrollbar is not there, they are moved to the opposite direction. `offsetHeight` and `scrollHeight` are both 0 as i have not defined any height, because i want the height to change with the content.

Comment: _"offsetHeight and scrollHeight are both 0 as i have not defined any height"_ - that's not the reason, the reason is that you are trying to read them while the element has `display:none`. Elements with that style do not have any dimensions at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @CBroe pointed out, i couldn't get the height of my element, or the children because it had `display: none` so to get around that:

```
let content = document.getElementById("content");
content.style.display = "block";
let height = content.offsetHeight;
content.style.display = "";
```

It's amazing something this dumb works so well. Now i can hide the scrollbar when i don't need it and fix the offset, that the scrollbar creates, when i do need it:

```
if (height < 300) {
    content.style.overflowY = "hidden";
} else {
    content.style.overflowY = "scroll";
    for (let kid of content.children) {
        kid.style.marginRight = "-16px";
    }
}
```

This solution has the added bonus, that it works well with my animation. A problem that the CSS only solution couldn't solve.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with this trick on the children:

```
margin-right: calc(100% - 300px);
```

And setting the parent `overflow` to `auto`

This works because here 100% is the elements full width. Without a scroll bar, 100% is 300px, so margin is set to 0. With a scroll bar, 100% is around 290px so margin is set to around -10, so the text stays centered.